C# Консольное приложение работает некорректно при запуске, но корректно при отладке
Написал вот такой код. https://gist.github.com/BTPRIMIGENIUS/4bf320150f24b3f38430c1aa4239307a
Вывод в консоль должен перечислить все карты на руке игрока. По логике программы это n случайных карт из колоды. Однако при запуске (ctrl + f5) мне стабильно выдает n одинаковых по масти и значению карт. Попытался найти ошибку сам - не нашел.
Но самое интересное произошло когда я запустил отладчик: программа заработала корректно и выдает n случайных карт в выводе. Я перепроверил 5 раз и стабильно результат один и тот же: корректная работа в отладчике и некорректная при обычной сборке.
Я не особо долго занимаюсь, так что прошу прощения если это какой-то известный баг.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //1. мало кто пойдет на сторонний сайт, чтоб искать ошибку => приложите тут основной код, где вы думаете ошибка в логике 2. почитайте справку, она поможет задать вопрос иначе 3. отладчик ... заработало => может там много методов, которые async не успевают проработать при обычном запуске, а при отладчике все таки время идет по шагам...

Вангую: Многопоточка? Random?

Да, реализация раздачи значений и мастей через Random. А что с этим делать то, чтобы наладилось?

А что с этим делать то, чтобы наладилось? - как пример, сделайте один класс Random и его переиспользуйте. Если постоянно его создавать, то рандомы созданные примерно в одно и то же время будут одни и те же числа выдавать.

Не используйте древний Framework 4.x. Проблему с Random уже очень давно починили. Пишите код например под .NET 8.
